# Can jQuery/Javascript/Ajax manage its own session cookies separate from browser cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a strange project where I need to embed some json data into a sharepoint page, and the requirements given to me mean it has to be done in an embedded javascript web snippet.  This data will be coming from a rest API which requires authentication.  I'm moderately familiar with this level of web programming, but most of my experience is not this deep with things like CORS and strange session work.

Locally, I do this in 2 steps.  I can make an authentication request (a POST request with action "login" and a username and password) which then gives my browser a session cookie, then I can do a second request with an action "getData" and everything works.

In the javascript, I am able to successfully login, but the session information does not persist to subsequent requests.  I'm not sure how to handle this, or if it's even possible.  I've played around with lots of code and tried using a jQuery Cookie plugin, but nothing seems to work.  I am open to any suggestions on a better way to solve this problem, or if there's a technical reason this will never work I need to know that.  Here's some prototype code:

```
var payload = { action : 'login' , username : 'username', password : 'password' }
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'https://fqdn/api',
    data: payload ,
    crossDomain: true,
    async: true,
    success: function (r, status, xhr ){
        var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        $('#DebugDiv1').text("test.Post.Success\n" + r + "\n" + xml_serializer.serializeToString(r) );
        var params = {'action':'getData'}
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://fqdn/api",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: params,
            crossDomain: true,
            async: true,
            success: function ( s, status, xhr ){
                var xml_serializer = new XMLSerializer();
                $('#DebugDiv3').html(s);
                $('#DebugDiv4').text("test.Post.Success\n" + r + "\n" + xml_serializer.serializeToString(s) );
            },
            error: function (s, status, xhr ){
                $('#DebugDiv3').text("test.Get.Error \n readyState: " + .readyState + "\nstatus: " + s.status + "\nstatusText: " + s.statusText );
                $('#DebugDiv4').text(s.responseText);
            }
        });                     
    },
    error: function (r, status, xhr ){
        $('#DebugDiv1').text("test.Post.Error \n readyState: " + r.readyState + "\nstatus: " + r.status + "\nstatusText: " + r.statusText );
        $('#DebugDiv2').text(JSON.stringify(r));
    }
});
```

Comment: If the response returns cookies, and you are making a cross domain request, then for those cookies to be included on future ajax requests to that same cross domain, you have to use `withCredentials: true` as an ajax header to tell the browser it needs to attach the cookies to the request for the other domain.

Comment: This can be done with the `$.ajax` `beforeSend` option that takes a callback, which is given the `xhr`, and the `withCredentials` property is on that variable.

Comment: Or you can use the `xhrFields` property directly.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I'm reading about this but I don't quite understand, do you have an example I can follow?  The tricky thing is I can't modify cors settings on the api server; I might be able to proxy it in apache.

Comment: Access to the cookies is not really a CORS issue.  If you have CORS issues, you would not be able to get a response back from the server in the first place, as it would be denied.  Take a look at that api link and search for the `xhrFields`.  It has an example of the withCredentials that I have mentioned.

Comment: You know what I had a plugin disabling cors for debugging, I do have a cors issue.  I'll try to solve that first.

Comment: It's working!!!!! thank you so much, you got me to where I needed to get!